# How to access additional UI element in Interface Builder (Storyboard)?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I can drag & drop a ui element from the "objects-selection" and add it to my current scene (marked red in the picture) but how can I edit it? Xcode doesn't show it in the editor, nor does double clicking the element make it visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with it.... Perhaps you could make it a subview of the current view in order to configure it and then remove it from its superview in code if you don't want it to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the hierarchy picture you provided, you are aware that the view you added is not part of the view controller's view hierarchy, correct? You would need to set the view controller's view property to this view in order to see it. If your intention was to add this as a subview of the current view, you should drag the view from the object repository directly onto the view. Alternatively, you can drag it from the View Controller Scene on the left and associate it as a sub view that way.

Also, note that when you pull the view onto the canvas, it's white. It may have been there and you just didn't see it if you had originally made it a subview of the current view.

Comment: My intention was to add a view and use it programmatically at a later time. So i'd like to "predefine" it to make it "ready to use". Therefore I'm confused what's the point of an Interface Builder which doesn't offer an option to edit views except for the current one. The only workaround i've got so far, is to create a temp scene/vc, edit the new view there and then drag and drop it to the scene where the new is actually needs to be.

Comment: Your workaround isn't really much of a work around. You can very easily create a UIView programmatically. There is no need, nor should you, create a view for the soul purpose of preparing it for use later. iOS / OS X development adopts a lazy-loading paradigm that you should adhere to.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the right way would be to add the extra view to the view controller's view, and have it hidden. Yes, it is going to be a pain to configure views this way. On the other hand this way those views do got the proper memory treatment and can get unloaded under memory pressure.